# Where to put test device IDs in google_mobile_ads package?

Tags: flutter, google-mobile-ads

I was using [`firebase_admob`](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_admob) package where I could add the test devices IDs with:

```dart
var targetingInfo = MobileAdTargetingInfo(
  testDevices: <String> [...]
);
```

But with [`google_mobile_ads`](https://pub.dev/packages/google_mobile_ads) I couldn't find anything similar to that. So, where can I put the test device IDs? Am I only left with using the test Ad unit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `updateRequestConfiguration` callback on the `MobileAds` instance, and provide test device IDs.

```dart
MobileAds.instance
  ..initialize()
  ..updateRequestConfiguration(RequestConfiguration(
    testDeviceIds: <String>[],
  ));
```